# NextJS FastRefresh/HotReload not working for mounted component

Tags: next.js, hot-reload

I'm building a website in NextJS. And I have a page that loads components using a lookup array.

```
import ComA from "./views/ComA";
import ComB from "./views/ComB";

export const data = [{
  route: "coma",
  title: "Component A",
  component: ComA
},
{
  route: "comb",
  title: "Component B",
  component: ComB
}]
```

Then I have a route, that takes the routename, and injects the given component into the page.

pages/views/[routename].tsx

```
const ViewPage= () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { routename } = router.query;
  const routeData = data.find((view) => view.route === routename);

  if (!routeData) {
    return <div>No route data found!</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-rows-auto3 gap-5 text-center">
      <div className="text-4xl">{routeData.title}</div>
      <div className="flex justify-center">{routeData.component()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ViewPage;
```

If I change something inside [routename].tsx everything works fine. The component is being hotreloaded. However, if I change something inside the given component that's being currently loaded, then hotreloading fails (as in it doesn't reload. It still rebuilds fine). And I am forced to manually reload the page with F5 for the changes to show.

I was thinking that it has something to do with how NextJS builds server side. But I have no clue how to change that, or even if I can.

Anybody who can help?